I get null in req.body when submitting data through pug form
this is pug form which is sending data to the requested url
   form.form.form-user-data(action='/submit-user-data' method='POST')
        .form__group
          label.form__label(for='name') Name
          input#name.form__input(type='text', value=`${user.name}`, required)
        .form__group.ma-bt-md
          label.form__label(for='email') Email
          input#email.form__input(type='email', value=`${user.email}`, required)
        .form__group.form__photo-upload
          img.form__user-photo(src=`img/${user.photo}`, alt='User photo')
          a.btn-text(href='') Choose new photo
        .form__group.right
          button.btn.btn--small.btn--green(type="submit") Save settings

and this is   is route i have created for getting data from the body
router.post('/submit-user-data', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body);
     res.status(200).send();
});

when clicking submit i am not recieving body only {} i am receving

Did you instruct express to use express.json()?

Browsers will submit values of <FORM> controls only if the control has a NAME attribute. ID alone won't do. So it should be, for example:
.form__group.ma-bt-md
   label.form__label(for='email') Email
   input#email.form__input(type='email', name='email' value=user.email, required)

Separately, you can assign Javascript expressions
(limited to some operators) directly to Html element attributes. There is no need to use interpolated strings.
